# modeling pupil dilation with Cocos3D / POD mesh

Tags: opengl-es, cocoapods, cocos3d

I have an eyeball mesh+texture from blender that I planned to use with Cocos3D. I need to be able to dynamically change the vertices that form the pupil to animate dilation and constriction. I've never used Cocos3D before, but I'm assuming since the POD format is a binary, I won't be able to access these vertices.

So what is the best way to handle this? If I create a second POD of just the pupil vertices, can I load that and run animation calls on those points? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the animation in an external editor. It's not easy to export them to the pod file.
In your app you can run the animation or set a specific frame of the animation. Take a look at the running men in the cocos3d-mashup-demo.

Comment: well the running men animations consist of object transformations. but i don't want to transform the object, i want to animate the texture vertices, which as far I as know can't be bundled in the POD. thanks anyway though.